Ex employer using my photos of dishes of my own creation after being fired
An ex employer is using my photos of my signature dishes. Was fired for asking for more family medical leave.  The daughter in law was taking photos of my recipe book as well and this was found out when she was showing me photos of a car she was trying to sell and while flipping through her phone she happened upon a photo of one of my recipes in my handwriting, and she used some lame excuse for wanting to cook a meal for her husband as she “loves” my cooking… what are my rights?  They do not have my permission to use my photos of my signature dishes.  They’ve renamed one of my photos from a chicken scallopini to a chicken picatta but still my photo, plating skills, etc.  I didn’t sign any waiver of any sorts, AND the owner blocked me on Facebook and now I understand one of the reasons is possibly hoping i wouldn’t see them.  Can I post something on their FB page asking to stop using my photos?   Do I have any legal rights here?  Please advise!

Were these photos made while you were working for them? If so, they may be work property and the employer owns the copyright, not you, unless your employment contract stated otherwise.

Yes, while I was working there.  but any advice about the DIL taking photos of my personal recipe book that was in my station that no one was allowed?

The copyright on the recipe book usually belongs to the publisher, not the author. So unless you self-published, they're the ones who would have to complain about her taking photographs.

Depends on where you live and work. While there are international conventions on copyright, the details still vary.
As the photographer, you may or may not hold the copyright to the actual photos you took. If taking the pictures can be argued to have been part of your job, then your employer may or may not have certain rights to use the pictures. However, there are jurisdictions where you retain the right to be named as the creator and the right not to have your creation modified. And you might be owed royalties, unless that is considered covered by the salary you earned while the pictures were taken.

The substance of recipes are not protected as intellectual property, except from people who have contractually entered into a non-disclosure agreement with you, although the wording of an actual recipe books could be protected. See, e.g., here. You can't copyright or patent it.
In all likelihood, food you made it not protected from being photographed either, particularly if the pictures were taken while you were employed and the dishes were made in the course of your employment with your ex-employer.
Basically, you have no rights in this situation.
